# How to position exported react elements correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a client that has a website they want built using react, and I have adobe cc do I thought I’d try mocking a website in adobe xd. I use the fireblade plugin for export, and everything looks fine as long as you don’t change the page size. Everything is placed with position:absolute :(, I think it looks great and I would like to be able to use all of the work I have put in on xd, I have a size for mobile, a medium size and a large size in xd. How can I scale a position:absolute page?
Thanks and sorry for the trouble!

Comment: "How can I scale a position:absolute page?" — I'd generally approach this by rewriting the layout from scratch.

Comment: Uhg i was hoping I didn’t need to do that, how do I keep all of the elements in the same relative spot though?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution! Guess what, all you have to do is convert the css position: absolute pixel values to a ratio of vw and vh! I am working on making a python extension that will automatically do it for you. I'll keep you posted on that here.